# Copying row from one df into everyone row in another

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have two dataframe

One df being just one row containing columns:

```
Description | Location
   Red      |  NH
```

The second df containing multiple rows (lets say 3 rows) that contain columns:

```
Item_Num | Quantity | Rating | 
    01   |    2     |   A    |
    02   |    5     |   B    |
    03   |    4     |   B+   |
```

I want to make it so that the first row in the first df is repeating for every row in the second.

```
   Description  | Location | Item_Num | Quantity | Rating | 
       Red      |  NH      |    01    |    2     |   A    |
       Red      |  NH      |    02    |    5     |   B    |
       Red      |  NH      |    03    |    4     |   B+   |
```

I tried playing around with loops but get an error. Joining them hasn't been working for me and there is no join key

Comment: Using `cbind(df1, df2)` will repeat the rows of `df1` to match the number of rows in `df2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `crossing` function from `tidyr` package, which creates combinations of rows of 2 datasets:

```
# example datasets
df1 = data.frame(Description = "Red",
                 Location = "NH")

df2 = data.frame(Item = 1:3,
                 Rating = c(20,25,30))

library(tidyr)

crossing(df1, df2)

#   Description Location Item Rating
# 1         Red       NH    1     20
# 2         Red       NH    2     25
# 3         Red       NH    3     30
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
second.df$Description <- first.df$Description
second.df$Location <- first.df$Location
```